# Sigma notation calculus, how to answer without calculator

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

How do I answer this without using a calculator?

$$\sum_{x=1}^{20}8x^{3}$$

Comment: is that supposed to be a division at the end??

Comment: define calculator.

Answer (score 4):

For this question you can use the formula

$$\sum_{x=1}^{n}x^{3}=(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^{2}$$

Using this formula where n = 20 you get 44100. Then you multiply by 8 to get 352800.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_{x=1}^{20}8x^{3}=8\sum_{x=1}^{20}x^{3}=8(1^3+2^3+3^3+...+20^3)=8(44100)=352800$$